# remove orphan temporary table in MySQL innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb

running mysql 5.6.19 on unubntu. have a big temp table left over after a crash. Thought to get rid of it as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html. I'm running:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u<username> -p<password> mydb -e "drop table \`#mysql50##sql-ib137812\`;"`
```

and getting `ERROR 1051 (42S02) at line 1: Unknown table 'mydb.#sql-ib137812'.
I confirmed that both .frm and .ibd files are in place and I can see the table in innodb_sys_tables. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found easier way, that works fine. It's even scriptable if you need to fix many servers.

1. Create empty temporary database. Let it be tmp1234
2. Move all tables from the original database to tmp1234
3. Drop the original database (it’s empty by now, all tables are in tmp1234)
4. Create the original database again
5. Move all tables from the temporary database to the original one.
   Drop the empty temporary database.

See some details in post [Resolving ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1: Table ‘sakila/#sql-ib712′ already exists](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/)

Comment: thanks, but that's rather extreme. I was looking for something less disruptive.